# DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'vuex' exceeded the quota

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I am getting around 500 array of objects from API, I try to save them in state through mutation commit I am facing above error.

#### action.js

```
export const fetchUserLessons = ({commit, getters}) => {
  let params = {
    companyId: getters.companyId,
    token: getters.getAccessToken
  }
  return getUserLessonDelta(params).then(response => {
    let batch = new BatchProcess(getUserLessons, params, response.data)
    return batch.process()
  }).then(response => {
    let userLessons = new UserLessons(response, getPdfUrl, params)
    commit('SET_LESSONS', userLessons)
  }).catch(error => {
    commit('ERROR', error)
  })
}
```

#### mutation.js

```
SET_LESSONS (state, payload) {
    state.lessons = payload.all
    state.done = payload.completed
    state.pending = payload.pending
    state.featured = payload.featured
}
```

#### error

> vuex-persistedstate.umd.js?5086:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException:
>   Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'vuex'
>   exceeded the quota.

Comment: Seem link your localstorage is full.

Comment: did you find a way to avoid this?

Comment: Yes, added pagination. Previously was fetching complete data due that memory was full.